# Get total amount available with Mongoose and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my application I register inputs and outputs of amounts, I need to register these movements in MongoDB.

When making a new entry or exit amount, I need to indicate the amount of entry or exit and the amount available. I require the classic operations of addition when it is input and subtraction when it is output, but also to obtain the amount available in the box either by adding with an input or subtracting with an output.

I am registering these movements using $inc to set the quantities but I don't know how I can directly obtain the addition or subtraction to the available quantity from the query with Mongoose. This is my code:

```
const newItem = async (req, res = response ) => {
const pettyCashId = req.params.id;
const type = req.params.type;

    let incomeAmount = 0;
    let expenseAmount = 0;

    if( type === 'income'){
        incomeAmount = req.body.incomeAmount;
        expenseAmount = 0;
    }

    if( type === 'expense'){
        expenseAmount = req.body.expenseAmount;
        incomeAmount = 0;
    }

    const itemToPush = {
        concept: req.body.concept,
        incomeAmount: incomeAmount,
        description: req.body.description,
        expenseAmount:expenseAmount,
        'createdBy':{
            uid: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username,
        }
    };


    let pettyCashItem = await PettyCashItems.findOneAndUpdate({ 'pettyCashId': pettyCashId },
        {
            $inc: { 
                totalIncomeAmount: incomeAmount, 
                totalexpenseAmount: expenseAmount,
                amountAvailable: ...
             },
            $push: { 
                'items': {
                  $each: [itemToPush],
                }
            }
        },{ new: true }
    );

    res.json ( pettyCashItem );
}
```

This is my Model:

```
const PettyCashItemsSchema = Schema (
  {
    pettyCashId:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'PettyCash',
        required: [true, 'La Caja Chica es Obligatoria']
    },
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Users',
        required: [true, 'El Usuario es obligatorio']
    },
    item: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    totalIncomeAmount: {
        type: Number,
        maxlength:50,
        default:0
    },
    totalexpenseAmount: {
        type: Number,
        maxlength:50,
        default:0
    },
    amountAvailable: {
        type: Number,
        maxlength:50,
        default:0
    },
    items:[{
        concept: {
            type: String,
            maxlength:50,
            required: [true, 'El Concepto es obligatorio']
        },
        incomeAmount:{
            type: Number,
            maxlength:50,
            default:0,
            required: [true, 'El Ingreso es obligatorio']
        },
        expenseAmount:{
            type: Number,
            maxlength:50,
            default:0,
            required: [true, 'El Egreso es obligatorio']
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            maxlength:50,
            required: [true, 'La Observación es obligatoria']
        },
        status: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
            required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        createdBy:{
            uid:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            username:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
    }],
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
    }
  }  
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Pass {new: true} if you want it to return the updated result
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: What I need is to obtain the available amount:                 amountAvailable: ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).